# Is there any way to display value and sparkchart in a single cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to display my cell like this:

[image: Sample]

Is this possible in Google Sheets? I tried with Spartline but it doesn't allow value and bar in the same cell.

Comment: not possible in one cell

Comment: Maybe `Google Analystic` is possible, since `Power BI` has such function